# 13.56 Mhz RFID security

Tags: encryption, authentication, cryptography, attack-prevention, rfid

I am new to the security field, i hope you can help me with this issue,

I am designing an access control system based on RFID 13.56 Mhz, and i am using Mifare RC522 IC, which is compatible with the mifare mini, 1k, 4k, ultralight, desfire Ev1 and Mifare Plus passive tags.

Does the selection of the tag type will affect the security of the communication, if i want to rate the compatible tags ascending?

How can such system be attacked, and how to prevent such attacks? and i want to test my system, is there any tools that i can develop to perform such attacks?

How to protect the communication between reader and tag in addition to ISO 14443 ?

how to protect the data on the tag, and the data on the micro-controller that is driving the reader?

Thanks in advance,

AT

Comment: You'll probably get better responses by asking a single question at a time. Note that product recommendations, including for testing tools, are off topic - they go out of date too quickly

Comment: ok, ignoring the test methods, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the main concern is that Mifare RC522 cards are easy to clone. Anyone with an Arduino and a $1.50 RFID module could copy someone's card and access your building.

If you're concerned about this risk, I do recommend you to check some of the HID RFID smart cards, they are not impossible to break, but definitely way harder.

Comment: It does seem to support the DESFire EV1. How do you evaluate the security of that?